# how to use case statement to check if column is null

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to create a stored procedure by using 3 tables,1st is Registration table,job seeker table,employment detail table.
In that I am having entries in 1st two tables.Till now I am not having any entry in employment detail table.

I am having following query:

```
select RD.FirstName,RD.LastName,
(select case when JR.profileHeadline=''
then 'No Resume Headline mentioned' 
else JR.profileHeadline end
from jobseekerReg JR)as profileHeadline ,
(select case when ED.designation=''
then 'No designation mentioned'
else ED.designation end
from employmentDetail ED)as designation,
(select case when ED.companyName=''
then 'No company name mentioned'
else ED.companyName end
from employmentDetail ED) as companyName,JR.location,
(select case when ED.funcArea=''
then 'No functional area mentioned'
else ED.funcArea end
from employmentDetail ED) as funcArea ,
(select case when ED.cmpIndustry=''
then 'No industry mentioned'
else ED.cmpIndustry end
from employmentDetail ED)as cmpIndustry,RD.BirthDay,
RD.Gender,JR.experience,
(select case when ED.salary=''
then 'No salary mentioned'
else ED.salary end
from employmentDetail ED)as salary ,JR.mobileNumber,JR.emailId,
JR.altEmailID,JR.jobSeekerAddrs,JR.maritalStatus,
(select case when JR.keySkills=''
then 'No keyskills mentioned'
else JR.keySkills end
from jobseekerReg JR)as keySkills
from RegistrationDetails RD join jobseekerReg JR on RD.Reg_Id=JR.regId
left outer join employmentDetail ED on ED.regId=JR.regId 
and ED.regId=2  where RD.Reg_Id=JR.regId and RD.Reg_Id=2 and JR.regId=2
```

The above query gives me correct output,but the problem is as I am not having any entry in employment table for regId=2, columns in this table gives output as null.
how should I handle this problem?
suggest me any solution
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `IsNull(fieldname, 'default value')` to set default data to null fields if that is what you want. Else there could be problem with populating the field with values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN ED.Salary IS NULL THEN 'No salary mentioned' ELSE ED.Salary END
```

But I think that in your case [`ISNULL()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) would be better:

```
select RD.FirstName,RD.LastName,
ISNULL(JR.profileHeadline, 'No Resume Headline mentioned') as profileHeadline ,
ISNULL(ED.designation, 'No designation mentioned') as designation,
ISNULL(ED.companyName, 'No company name mentioned')  as companyName, 
JR.location,
ISNULL(ED.funcArea, 'No functional area mentioned') as funcArea ,
ISNULL(ED.cmpIndustry, 'No industry mentioned') as cmpIndustry,
RD.BirthDay,
RD.Gender, JR.experience,
ISNULL(ED.salary, 'No salary mentioned' as salary ,
JR.mobileNumber,JR.emailId,
JR.altEmailID,JR.jobSeekerAddrs,JR.maritalStatus,
ISNULL(JR.keySkills, 'No keyskills mentioned') as keySkills
from RegistrationDetails RD join jobseekerReg JR on RD.Reg_Id=JR.regId
left outer join employmentDetail ED on ED.regId=JR.regId 
and ED.regId=2  where RD.Reg_Id=JR.regId and RD.Reg_Id=2 and JR.regId=2
```

Comment: the above query works fine for fields from employment details.And it is not giving any value in fields from registration table and job seeker table

Comment: @AshwiniAgivalem, you should look for a problem in your data. Have I answered on your original question?